# PHP is breaking my code

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, echo

I'm trying to deploy a site but I get errors when the PHP/MySql code goes on the server. It worked fine in development but not in production.

My code gets down to here, with no problems:

```
<div class="content">
  <section class="col1">
   <h1>Read reviews or write us one</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="col2">
   <button type="button" class="read">Read Reviews</button>
    <?php include ('display.php'); ?>
```

Then when I check the source code, the HTML just stops there. I'm guessing there's something wrong with my PHP in the display.php file, which looks like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','communi3_root',"password");
mysql_select_db('communi3_cfds','communi3@localhost',"password") or die(mysql_error());
$query = "select * from reviews";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "<table class='displayReviews' border='1' style='width:100%;'>";
echo "<tr stlye='display:block;margin:0em auto;'><th>Name</th><th>Review</th><th>Date</th></tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['monicker'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['review'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['date'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: I've done that when wasted, too. Um, OP how do you plan to debug any of your code if you can't see error messages? You need to go find the php.ini file on your server and turn errors and warnings on (it explains how) then restart apache so while you're developing this you can see what's going on. Otherwise... good luck.

Comment: `mysql_select_db()` is not the same as `mysql_connect()` ... you are connecting twice, but using the wrong function the second time. Also, you should not use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use `PDO` or `MySQLi` instead. Further, printing `mysql_error()` to the page means that people will see it, if something goes wrong, which is very bad security. You should log errors instead. Ehm, and `stlye` is not a valid HTML attribute. I am not going to edit this comment any more... you should really clean up your code...

Comment: In second line there is nothing after or. There are lots of errors in your php code as have been pointed above by others.

Comment: @RolenKoh Yes there is. Scroll to the right.

Comment: @ Sverri M. Olsen Yes there is sorry but it is still bad formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after removing some error

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','communi3_root',"password");
    mysql_select_db('communi3_cfds',$con) or               die(mysql_error());
    $query = "select * from reviews";
    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "<table class='displayReviews' border='1' style='width:100%;'>";
    echo "<tr stlye='display:block;margin:0em auto;'><th>Name</th><th>Review</th><th>Date</th></tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><td>"; 
        echo $row['monicker'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['review'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['date'];
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: A huge thanks to @Qaisar Satti. I've gotten it working now, and while it's not very nice code, it will have to do as it's functional. Maybe I'll come back and fix it properly when I've got more experience with this type of code, but as for now I'm happy with having a functional site on the net with custom software (albeit, not very elegant). I think it's not too bad for a beginner. Thanks to everyone else for their "help". I'll try to work on getting my skills a bit more up-to-date.